# Typo on 'PCT, Spin and Statistics, and All That'

Tags: wavefunction, spin-statistics, textbook-erratum

On page 163, formula (4-76) says

$$
    (Ψ_{10},…Ψ_0)=…
$$

but it should say

$$
    (Ψ_{10},…Ψ_{10})=…
$$
right?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. It should be a typo.